# Generate random PESEL number

Tags: code-golf, number, random, generation

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL):

> **PESEL** is the
>   national identification number used in Poland since 1979. It always
>   has 11 digits, identifies just one person and cannot be changed to
>   another one.
>
> It has the form of YYMMDDZZZXQ, where YYMMDD is the date of birth
>   (with century encoded in month field), ZZZ is the personal
>   identification number, X denotes sex (even number for females, odd
>   number for males) and Q is a control digit, which is used to verify
>   whether a given PESEL is correct or not.
>
> Having a PESEL in the form of ABCDEF GHIJK, one can check the
>   vailidity of the number by computing the following expression:
>
> A*1 + B*3 + C*7 + D*9 + E*1 + F*3 + G*7 + H*9 + I*1 + J*3
>
> Then the last digit of the result should be subtracted from 10. If the
>   result of the last operation is not equal to the last digit of a given
>   PESEL, the PESEL is incorrect. This system works reliably well for
>   catching one-digit mistakes and digit swaps.

Provide **a short program to generate random, valid PESEL number**:

1. It has to be a PESEL a person born in either 20th or 21st century
2. The birth birth date has to be random but doesn't have to validate leap years or number of days in a month (i.e. the numbers representing the day number have to be between `01` and `31`)
3. All valid PESELs in this date range (01.01.1990-31.12.2099) must be possible
4. The shortest code (i.e. complete program code), in bytes, wins.

Comment: How random? eg, must all digits vary, must eg all 20th century birthdays be possible, and no others? Seems like this can be subverted by solutions that just coin toss between male and female.

Comment: @bazzargh, good point - let it be a PESEL for a person born in either 20th or 21st century.

Comment: Actually my point is more that 'random' can mean 'one of a fixed set of choices'. If you pick a PESEL of A001100000Q then Q=10-A, it's still 'random', with a random date, but way less code. Saying that all valid PESELs for your date range must be possible blocks tricks like this.

Comment: @bazzargh Changed the question once again.

Comment: Please correct the algorithm: The current version allows the last digit to be `10`. The [Polish Wikipedia version](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL) uses a modulo 10 operation to get 0 in this case.

Comment: The gender entry uses the full range `0` to `9` to encode male and female (1 bit). What's the purpose of this "random noise"? Or are there further specification on the gender field that I have missed?

Comment: The century is encoded in the month field. This is neither specified in the question or links. For example, it is explained in the [Polish Wikipedia article](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL).

Comment: Please clarify the restrictions on the date. The question says, that all dates of the 20th and 21st century must be possible. It is unclear, if invalid dates are allowed. It makes a huge difference in a code golf competition, if the date has to be validated, e.g. excluding YYYY-02-29 with YYYY not being a leap year.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL for an explanation, in English, of the PESEL encoding.

Comment: The control digit is found by taking the remainder of the number modulus 10.   It is not found by subtraction.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: Missed that, the Polish version has a nice table instead.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: The result of the expression in the question is subtracted from 10 and then the control digit is the remainder of the number modulus 10.

Comment: Isn't that the same as finding the remainder of division by 10. (I.e. the subtraction is unnecessary.)

Comment: @DavidCarraher: 136 % 10 = 7 is different from (10 - (137 % 10)) % 10 = 3. (Of course there is room for optimization in the calculation of the control digit.)

Comment: you are correct (of course)!

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 162 bytes

```perl
@a=map{$==rand 10}0..9;$"='';$a[5]%=2if($a[4]%=4)==3;"@a[4,5]"||$a[5]++;$a[3]=($a[2]%=4)%2?$a[3]%3:1+$a[3]%9;$f=9;for(@a){$x+=$f*$_;$f-=$f%10==7?4:2}print@a,$x%10
```

### Ungolfed:

```perl
# Array with random digits
# ------------------------
@a = map { $= = rand 10} 0..9;
# do not insert a space, if arrays are interpolated into strings
$" = ''; #"

# Day correction
# --------------
# The day must be in the range of "01" to "31":
# * map first digit to "0" to "3": $a[4] %= 4
# * map second digit to "0" to "1" if first digit is "3"
$a[5] %= 2 if ($a[4] %= 4 ) == 3;
# * set day to "01" if day is "00"
"@a[4,5]" || $a[5]++;

# Month correction
# ----------------
# The month must be in the range "01" to "12" or "21" to "32"
# to get a valid month and century:
# * map the month to "00" to "39"
# * if the first digit is odd (catching both centuries at once)
#   * then map the second digit to "0" to "2"      (for months: 10..12)
#   * otherwise map the second digit to "1" to "9" (for months: 01-09)
$a[3] = ($a[2] %= 4) % 2 ? $a[3] % 3: 1 + $a[3] % 9;

# Calculate the control digit
# ---------------------------
# Because of the modulo 10 operations, the formula for the calculation
# of the control digit is rewritten from
# Q = (10 - ((A + 3B + 7C + 9D + E + 3F + 7G + 9H + I + J) % 10)) % 10
# to
# Q = (9A + 7B + 3C + D - E - 3F -7G - 9H - 11I - 11J) % 10
$f = 9;
for (@a) {
    $x += $f * $_;
    $f -= $f % 10 == 7 ? 4 : 2
}

# Print the result and control digit
print @a, $x % 10


# TEST section
# ------------

;$Q = $x % 10; # remember control digit in $Q

# Pretty print PESEL
print "\n\n",
  "YY MM DD ZZZ X Q\n",
  "@a[0,1] @a[2,3] @a[4,5] @a[6,7,8] $a[9] $Q\n";
print "\n";

# Pretty print the date
$month = "@a[2,3]";
$century = "??";
$century = "19" if $month >= 1 and $month <= 12;
$century = "20" if $month >= 21 and $month <= 32;
printf "Date: $century@a[0,1]-%02d-@a[4,5]\n", $month % 20;
print "\n";

# Pretty print the gender
print "Gender: ", $a[9] % 2 ? "male" : "female", "\n";
print "\n";

# Calculate the control date the official way
print "Control digit:\n";
$sum = 0;
$f = 0;
for (my ($i, $f) = (0, 1); $i<10; $i++, $f+=2) {
    $f %= 10;
    $f += 2 if $f == 5;
    printf "  $a[$i] * $f = %2d\n", $a[$i] * $f;
    $sum += $a[$i] * $f;
}
print "  ", "-" x 10, "\n";
printf "  %10d\n", $sum;
printf "  $Q = (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10 = %d\n", (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10;
```

### Examples

```
83102570819

YY MM DD ZZZ X Q
83 10 25 708 1 9

Date: 1983-10-25

Gender: male

Control digit:
  8 * 1 =  8
  3 * 3 =  9
  1 * 7 =  7
  0 * 9 =  0
  2 * 1 =  2
  5 * 3 = 15
  7 * 7 = 49
  0 * 9 =  0
  8 * 1 =  8
  1 * 3 =  3
  ----------
         101
  9 = (10 - (101 % 10)) % 10 = 9
```

```
20233143600

YY MM DD ZZZ X Q
20 23 31 436 0 0

Date: 2020-03-31

Gender: female

Control digit:
  2 * 1 =  2
  0 * 3 =  0
  2 * 7 = 14
  3 * 9 = 27
  3 * 1 =  3
  1 * 3 =  3
  4 * 7 = 28
  3 * 9 = 27
  6 * 1 =  6
  0 * 3 =  0
  ----------
         110
  0 = (10 - (110 % 10)) % 10 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>247</s> 270

A bit long but there are many details to take into consideration:

- Allow any valid birth date between Jan. 1, 1900 and Dec. 31, 2099;  Feb. 29 included in leap years.
- Pad all numbers left with zeros: e.g. Month 3 becomes "03" so any PESEL will have exactly 11 digits.
- Add 20 to month if in 21st century (2000-2099)

### Ungolfed

Below the components are named for convenience.

```
g:=Module[{year,month,day,centuryIncrement,id,controlDigit,pesel},
{year,month,day}=DatePlus[{1900,1,1},RandomInteger[73048]];
centuryIncrement=20*Boole[year>= 2000];
Print[Row@{{year,month,day},"  ",DateString[{year,month,day},{"MonthName"," ","Day",", ","Year"}]},
"\ncentury increment: ",centuryIncrement,
"\nID: ",id=PadLeft[IntegerDigits@RandomInteger[999],3],
"\nsex: ",sex=RandomInteger[1]];
f=Flatten[{{IntegerDigits@year,PadLeft[IntegerDigits[month+centuryIncrement],2],
PadLeft[IntegerDigits@day,2]},id,sex}][[3;;12]];
Print["control digit: ",controlDigit=Mod[10-IntegerDigits[Tr@Thread[Times[f,{1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3}]]][[-1]],10],
"\nPESEL: ",""<>ToString/@PadLeft[Append[f,controlDigit]]]]
```

### Examples

```
g
```

> {1931,2,9}  February 09, 1931
>   century increment: 0
>   ID: {0,8,8}
>   sex: 0
>   control digit: 9
>   PESEL: 31020908809

---

```
g
```

> {2067,6,27}  June 27, 2067
>   century increment: 20
>   ID: {9,0,8}
>   sex: 0
>   control digit: 1  
>   PESEL: 67262790801

---

```
g
```

> {1967,9,5}  September 05, 1967
>   century increment: 0
>   ID: {5,0,0}
>   sex: 0
>   control digit: 2
>   PESEL: 67090550002

---

### Golfed

```
g:=Module[{y,m,d,i=IntegerDigits,p=PadLeft,r=RandomInteger},{y,m,d}=DatePlus[{1900,1,1},r[73048]];
f=Flatten[{{i@y,p[i[m+20*Boole[y>= 2000]],2],p[i@d,2]},p[i@r[999],3],r[1]}][[3;;12]];
""<>ToString/@p[Append[f,Mod[10-i[Tr@Thread[Times[f,{1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3}]]][[-1]],10]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 151

```
echo($n=date("ymd",rand(-2e9,4e9)).rand(101,999).rand()%10).(10-($n[0]+3*$n[1]+7*$n[2]+9*$n[3]+$n[4]+3*$n[5]+7*$n[6]+9*$n[7]+$n[8]+3*$n[9])%10);
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/DYeXf9

Comment: It doesn't generate valid PESEL number.

Comment: Oh, ok... fixing it.

Comment: The output it too long: 14 digits instead of 11.

Comment: How do you ensure the validity of a date?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 220

This generates random date between 1900-01-01 and 2099-12-31, but it does not check whether the number of days in the month is valid.

Value for gender ranges from 0 - 9.

This is as few characters as I could get it:

```
r=RandomInteger;a=r@9;b=r@9;m=r@11+1+r@1*20;c=Floor[m/10];d=m~Mod~10;n=r@30+1;e=Floor[n/10];f=n~Mod~10;g=r@9;h=r@9;i=r@9;j=r@9;k=Mod[10-Mod[a+3b+7c+9d+e+3f+7g+9h+i+3j,10],10];StringJoin[ToString/@{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}]
```

### Sample output:

```
04020506179
```

```
34230487249
```

```
26321891950
```

```
45260298217
```

### Ungolfed:

```
r=RandomInteger;

a=r@9; (*year*)
b=r@9;

month=r@11+1+r@1*20;
c=Floor[month/10];
d=month~Mod~10;

day=r@30+1;
e=Floor[day/10];
f=day~Mod~10;

g=r@9; (*personal ID*)
h=r@9;
i=r@9;

j=r@9; (*gender*)

k=Mod[10-Mod[a+3b+7c+9d+e+3f+7g+9h+i+3j,10],10]; (*control digit*)

StringJoin[ToString/@{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}]
```

Comment: `day=r@30+1` assumes that any month can have 31 days?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 157 chars

```
""<>ToString/@Join[#,{Mod[-#.{1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3},10]}]&@Flatten@{IntegerDigits[#,10,2]&/@RandomChoice@DateRange[{1990,1,1},{2099,12,31}],9~RandomInteger~4}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, 156 bytes

```
a=datestr(693961+randi(73049),'yyyymmdd');a(5)=a(5)+2*(a(1)>49);A=a(3:8)-48;b=randi(10,1,4);[[A b mod(10-mod(sum(('1379137913'-48).*[A b]),10),10)]+48 '']
```

Ungolfed with some explanation:

```
a=datestr(693961+randi(73049),'yyyymmdd');
  -- generates date serial number in desired range and converts do string
a(5)=a(5)+2*(a(1)>49);
  -- modifies the first digit of the month if year >= 2000 (first digit >1)
A=a(3:8)-48;
  -- gets the "YYMMDD" part and converts from string to array of numbers
b=randi(10,1,4)-1;
  -- gets remaining 4 random digits ("ZZZX")
[[A b mod(10-mod(sum(('1379137913'-48).*[A b]),10),10)]+48 '']
  -- computes the last digit and converts the whole thing to string
```